# Every 1-manifold has a CW decomposition

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I have a quick question about the following proof of a theorem in Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*.

**Theorem 5.25.** Every 1-manifold admits a CW decomposition.

**Proof.**
Part 1
[image: image1]
Part 2
[image: image2]

In the seventh line of Part 2, it is claimed that the 1-cell $e$ is open in $M$, but I fail to see why this is true, since open cells are not necessarily open in the space they are embedded in.

I tried to justify this by arguing that $\mathcal{E}_n$ is a CW decomposition of $M_n$, since it is a finite cell complex, and then invoke the theorem that tells us that (open) $n$-cells of an $n$-dimensional CW complex is open. But this still does not tell us that $e$ is open in $M$ - it only tells us that $e$ is open in $M_n$, which is not necessarily open in $M$.

Can someone explain how one can show that $e$ is open in $M$?

Comment: Please don't use images unless they are strictly necessary. In this case, you could easily use MathJax to summarise the salient points of the argument you are having difficulties with. You might even find that writing down that summary helped you understand the proof.

Comment: That set is open in $M$ because it is a coordinate ball, not because it is an open cell.